# Altering model after field validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm implementing a tagging system. Currently, the models look like this:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_TAG_LENGTH)


class TagManager(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="referrers")

    def associate_tag(self, tag_label: str):
        . . .
```

And I have a custom field that cuts its input on commas so the user can enter tags as a comma-separated list:

```py
class TagsField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return []
        return [tag.strip() for tag in value.split(',')]
```

Finally, I have the model and form where these are used:

```py
class Thing(models.Model):
    tags = models.OneToOneField(TagManager, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class ThingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = TagsField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Tags", "required": False}))

    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ["tags"]
```

## Problem

My issue is that if I populate and validate the form:

```
form = ThingForm(data={"tags": ["One", "Two"]})
form.is_valid()
```

I get errors:

```
{'tags': ["“["One", "Two"]” value must be an integer."]}
```

Which I'm guessing is because it's trying to place the stringified list in the `OneToOneField`, which isn't going to work.

What I really need to do is after validating the field, I need to iterate the results of `to_python`, and call `thing_instance.tags.associate_tag` on each of the validated tag strings.

Is there a "hook" method on forms that will allow me to do this cleanly? I've read over the docs and `Form` source and can't find any obvious candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I realized as I was writing this that it's a `clean_*` method that I need. This didn't strike me as "cleaning" on first brush, so I ignored it.

The solution was to add a `clean_tags` method to the `ThingForm` class:

```py
def clean_tags(self):
    tags = self.cleaned_data["tags"]
    for tag in tags:
        self.instance.tags.associate_tag(tag)
    return self.instance.tags.pk
```

It associates the cleaned tags, and then returns the PK of the `TagManager` they were added to.